# Incorrect hex addition on memory mapped address and offsets in C++

Tags: c++, hex

Let's start with what I am able to get working and then what is not working, and then hopefully the community can help me figure out why.

Let's say I have the following class:

```
#define BASE        0x20200000 /* base GPIO address in memory mapped IO*/
#define GPSET0      0x1c    /* Pin Output Set */
#define GPCLR0      0x28    /* Pin Output Clear */
class LedDriver
{
    void set_bit(int value) 
    {
        if (value) {
           reg = GPSET0;
        } else {
           reg = GPCLR0;
        }
        // set bit 15 based on the register being used
        volatile int* address = ((volatile int*) (BASE+reg);
        *(address) |= (1 << 15);
    }
}
```

This works fine, and the end result is the LED blinking on and off.  Great!

Now I want to use class members for the same, such as:

```
class LedDriver
{
    // some class members
   volatile const int BASE          = 0x20200000; /* base GPIO address in memory mapped IO*/
   volatile const int GPSET0        = 0x1c; /* Pin Output Set */
   volatile const int GPCLR0        = 0x28; /* Pin Output Clear */

    void set_bit(int value) 
    {
        if (value) {
            reg = GPSET0;
        } else {
            reg = GPCLR0;
        }
        // set bit 15 based on the register being used
        volatile int* address = ((volatile int*) (BASE+reg);
        *(address)|= (1 << 15);
    }
}
```

But this does not work.  I am not experienced enough in C++ to know why, but I do think it has to do with the hex addition or somehow the variable is being treated differently than the macro.

Is my assumption correct? If so, is there a way to make it work, or is it not intended to work in this way?

One final note: I am deliberately avoiding any stdlib functions right now with the compiler flag `-nostdlib` for the purposes of learning.

Comment: What is the point of making a variable `volatile` and `const` both? What does that even mean? :-/

Comment: Your examples can't possibly compile. There are more opening parentheses than closing ones.

Comment: doesn't volatile stop the compiler from doing any optimization on it? const just means it doesn't change.  but the compiler can optimize it out if it isn't referenced again

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I will update it.  What I have is longer so I just took pieces of it.  I assume you both examples compile in the real version of the code

Comment: @IgorTandetnik updated!

Comment: Are you building on a 16-bit system? Is `sizeof(int) == 2`, by any chance?

Comment: @Nawaz -- re: `const volatile` -- `const` means that this code won't modify it; `volatile` means that something else might modify it. They're not mutually exclusive, but the `volatile` is not needed here.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik no I am not, 32-bit

Comment: How big is an `int` on this system? Does `0x20200000` fit in an `int`?

Comment: Double-check that. The only way I see the second example could differ from the first is if casting 0x20200000 to `int` (as in `int BASE = 0x20200000`) loses significant bits.

Comment: It should, it is an Rpi zero with broadcom 2835 chip (32 bit)

Comment: Don't make assumptions based on labels like "32 bit" or "16 bit". Check the size of `int`. And check the **actual value** that `BASE` ends up with; as Igor suggests, it's probably not what you want it to be.

Comment: I was using `typedef unsigned int            uint32_t;` so those examples should be re-written to `uint32_t`.  But I will check on that plus change them to `typedef unsigned long long int  uint64_t;`  Thanks for the starting point

Comment: @PeteBecker that's more difficult since I am on bare metal.  But I get your point.  I do have serial output over UART.  I checked and you are correct, it is not what I think it is.  So the reason for what is the register size?

Comment: 'unsigned int uint32_t` -- this is dangerous unless you **know** that `unsigned int` is 32 bits wide. Even if it is, it's misleading because it won't necessarily be 32 bits wide with a different compiler. If you need an integral type that's always at least 32 bits wide, use `long` or `unsigned long`. If you need an integral type that's always at least 64 bits wide, use `long long` or `unsigned long long`.

Comment: And in fact, use `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` for "integer at least large enough to hold any memory address", which it looks like what you need here.